# Changing charset to utf-16 in meta tag breaks the app

Tags: typescript

I misteknaly changed meta charset from utf-8 to utf-16 in html head. Now app compiles successfully but there are HTML tags when I open the tab. I changed it back to utf-8 but it's still showing ma same HTML tags. You can see the screenshot below:

[image]

It shows this error `No base href set. Please provide a value for the APP_BASE_HREF token or add a base element to the document.` even though I did not change anything else and the base URL is still there as it used to be.

I only changed index.html. I change `<meta charset="utf-8">` to `<meta charset="utf-16">`. I tried to stop and rerun the app and also restarted my PC. I then created a new Angular app and changed the same meta tag, it was also broken. Strange.

Comment: Which file(s) did you change the charset in? Did you restart the server after changing it back (i.e. have you tried turning it on and off again)?

Comment: @JoachimSauer I only changed index.html. I change  <meta charset="utf-8"> to <meta charset="utf-16">. I tried to stop and rerun the app and also restarted my PC. I then created a new Angular app and changed the same meta tag, it was also broken. Strange.

Comment: The question mark is a place holder for a non-representable char, probably `\u0000`, as you mentioned UTF-16. Check the index.html in a encoding aware editor like Notepad++.

Comment: It's understandable why changing the meta tag to UTF-16 breaks your stuff: This is meant to *describe* the charset of the current file. If you don't actually convert the file to UTF-16 and just change that text, then it's messed up. But if you change it back to UTF-8 (or convert the file to UTF-16 correctly) then it should all be fine. Note that there's barely any reason to actually use UTF-16 here. UTF-8 is [really all you need](http://utf8everywhere.org/).

Comment: @JoachimSauer what should I do now? It is supposed to work fine when I added utf-8 back.

Comment: @AlamzaibFarooq: It's unclear what else broke, maybe try Joops suggestion. If you use git, check the diff to see if any other unexpected changes have been done. Or if you use an IDE with a local history view, check that.

Comment: @JoachimSauer but what about the newly created app? It has the same behavior. You can also reproduce this issue easily.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Yes, you were right. I just opened local history in my WebStorm and there was wrong encoded content added my me. I reverted it and now it's resolved.

Comment: Good to know that helped. In the future you will know to check that as one of the first steps ;-)

Comment: @JoachimSauer Yes

Answer (score 0):

As @joachimSauer commented it was in my local history in WebStorm. I reverted back and issue is resolved now.